# can't acces root phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get a root acces to my phpmyadmin. I already tried to go into config.inc.php but i did not succed.

[image]

**Mysql version**

[image]

**config.inc.php**

[image]

If someone know how can i found root password, please tell me.

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 0):

default database username: root and the password is empty

Comment: It dosent work for me

Comment: @JohnDoe make sure you do not enter any space in your username (and also make sure to not enter anything in the password field) - if it still doesn't work then you probably changed the default password so you need to reset it, refer to the duplicated question

Comment: Ok i'll refer to it, thanks you for helping me

Comment: @JohnDoe The Password is set to 'password' in some versions - maybe you are lucky in this

Comment: i'm not lucky then  ... and the solution does not work me